# Angular 2 How do I call a service method when an observable changes/when a services returns new results?

Tags: angularjs, angular, service, observable

I have a simple app component with a search input and an observable `resultItems: Observable<Array<string>>;` powered by a search service that returns results to the UI via *ngFor.  There is also a leaflet map that should render the locations of the results.  The search service works well and I can render the location of one result in the map onclick.   My question is:  What is the recommended way to call the map service mapResults every time the search service returns new results or the observable changes?  I can imagine how I could create a custom pipe that would iterate over the parks in the service results and call mapservice.mapResult but that seems odd since the pipe wouldn't return anything to the UI and I'm a little concerned with performance, understanding little about pure and impure pipes.  I have also seen mention of a process by which you subscribe to changes of an observable, but I'm lost with the semantics and changes among API versions.

I apologize if this is a problem of poor design. I only have a few weeks of Angular learning and I admittedly haven't read the documentation thoroughly. Please point any and all issues you see.

simple Search Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URLSearchParams, Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export default class ParkSearchService {

    constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) { }

    search(parkSearchterm: string) {
        var search = new URLSearchParams()
        search.set('q', 'PARK_NAME:*' + parkSearchterm+'*');
        search.set('wt', 'json');

        search.set('json.wrf','JSONP_CALLBACK')

        var test = this.jsonp
            .get('http://parksearch/parks_full/select?', { search })
            .map((response) => response.json()['response']['docs']);

        return test

    }
}
```

exert from app.component.html

```
  <md-card *ngFor="let item of resultItems | async; let i = index"
                 class="search-result"
                 [ngClass]="{ 'selected-result': selectedIndex === i }">
            <md-card-header class="clickable"
                            (click)="showBoundary(item)"
                            md-tooltip="Zoom to park">
                <md-card-title>{{item.PARK_NAME}}</md-card-title>
            </md-card-header>
            <md-card-content style="height: 75px; overflow-y: auto">
                <button md-button
                        color="primary"
                        md-tooltip="more info"
                        (click)="openDtl(item.PARK_HOME_PAGE_URL)">
                    <md-icon>info</md-icon>
                    <span>Details...</span>
                </button>
                <button md-button
                        color="primary"
                        md-tooltip="open park website"
                        (click)="openParkURL(item.PARK_HOME_PAGE_URL)">
                    <md-icon>web</md-icon>
                    <span>WebSite</span>
                </button>
                Amenties: {{ item.AMEN_LIST }}
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
```

app.component.ts  (forgot to include)

```
 export class AppComponent {
    private selectedIndex: number;
    public events: any[] = [];
    //park search items
    resultItems: Observable<Array<string>>;
    parkSearchterm = new FormControl();

    //setup resultitems
    ngOnInit() {
            this.mapService.initialize();
            this.resultItems = this.parkSearchterm.valueChanges
                .debounceTime(400)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .switchMap(parkSearchterm => this.parkSearchService.search(parkSearchterm));
```

map service:

```
//Thanks for the help getting started https://github.com/haoliangyu
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, GeoJSON } from 'leaflet';

@Injectable()
export default class MapService {
    public map: Map;
    private currentLayer: GeoJSON;
    private resultsLayer: any;
    private resultfeatureCollection: any;

    constructor() {

    }

    initialize() {
        if (this.map) {
            return;
        }

        this.map = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl: true,
            zoom: 6,
            minZoom: 3,
            maxZoom: 19
        });

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://hot.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team</a>'
        }).addTo(this.map);

        L.control.scale().addTo(this.map);

        //Add the results layer
        this.resultsLayer = L.geoJSON(this.resultfeatureCollection, {
            style: () => {
                return {
                    color: '#ff00005',
                    fillColor: '#3F51B5'
                };
            }
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }
    mapResults(park) {
        //update the restults layer
        let resultfeatureCollection: GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<any> = {
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
            features: [
                {
                    type: 'Feature',
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Polygon",
                        coordinates: JSON.parse(park.BBOX[0])
                    },
                    properties: {
                        name: 'test'
                    }
                }
            ]
        };

        this.resultsLayer.addData(resultfeatureCollection);
        this.map.fitBounds(this.resultsLayer.getBounds());
    }



}
```

Comment: Where/How is `resultItems` set in your code?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
        this.mapService.initialize();
        this.resultItems = this.parkSearchterm.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(400)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap(parkSearchterm => this.parkSearchService.search(parkSearchterm));
      
    }

Comment: I updated the code snippets to include the more about the resultitems observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe on observer and call then search is changed. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#reuse

After get result from server, put it to array. Angular will update the data in the template itself, this is the fastest way.

Comment: I've read this, but it isn't explicit enough for me.  How do I subscribe to changes to  resultItems: Observable<Array<string>>;?

Comment: Observable<Array<string>>.subscribe((data)=>{ console.log('My changed data');console.log(data);});

Comment: Thanks very much! That's exactly what I was hoping for.  I tried something similar but must have had an error in the (data) => part.

Comment: @AliGoodnature-Wieckowicz please consider my answer. `.subscribe(`ing directly will make 2 calls to the API each time the user makes a new search.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to what you need: You already have an observable stream created for your results, called `resultItems`, that is right. Then on your template, when you use it through the `async` pipe what Angular does internally is subscribes to this stream to get its values.

So if you want to "also" map when `resultItems` yields is by subscribing to it by yourself as well. There's a catch though: by default every subscription duplicates the workload for the stream, meaning that every time the user makes a new search it would run the API call twice: 1 for the `async` subscription and another one for your `.subscribe`.

The way to resolve that is by using `.publish()`: What this allows is to share the result of an stream between many subscribers, so your code would look like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mapService.initialize();
    this.resultItems = this.parkSearchterm.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(parkSearchterm => this.parkSearchService.search(parkSearchterm))
        .publish();
    // With publish() we are sharing the items from this stream to all of their subscribers
    // We just need to tell it to do the "first subscription"
    this.resultConnection = this.resultItems.connect();
    // This "resultConnection" is the base subscription... We will have to dispose it in our ngOnDestroy method or we might get memory leaks

    // Now we can tell the map service to update when we get a value:
    this.resultItems.subscribe((park) => this.mapService.mapResults(park));
    // (Not sure if the data types are correct, I assume you can map them)
    // When `async` calls .subscribe() to do his job, we won't get duplicate API calls thanks to .publish()
}
```

To clarify, what `connect()` does is subscribe to the original stream, and start forwarding the values recieved to the subscribers of the published stream (`this.resultItems`). Now you are the owner of that subscription, so you are responsible of disposing it whenever you don't need more searches.